# Linking to third-party site for system DLL

Tags: discussion, hyperlinks

I came across [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30891095/1270789) when reviewing:

> U can find this file here `http://fix4dll.com/msvcp120_dll` .

I don't know how trustworthy that site is, or how trustworthy a recommendation from someone using 'U' is, but Chrome gave me two separate warnings about downloading it, and the resultant DLL is hosted on that `fix4dll` site. I think this deserves a moderator flag, but I thought I'd check here first.

Comment: The answer has been deleted, most likely as a result of this post.